# Is there a possibility to connect a ESP8266 to the Google Firestore without using Google IOT platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am working on a project whereby I want to connect my ESP8266 (NodeMCU) to the google **Firestore** (not the RT-Firebase) to read / retrieve some data and maybe write something to it aswell.

I have already tried with a simple REST API GET-request but That kept on failing. Any guides, help, examples?

Here below my code of a simple Get-request that keeps on giving an error

```
[HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection refused
```

```
void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){


  http.begin("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/edubox-49528/databases/(default)/documents/nodes?&key=[API-KEY]");
  int httpCode = http.GET(); //Send the request
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    String payload = http.getString(); //Get the request response payload
    Serial.println(payload); //Print the response payload
  }
  else {
    Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
  }
  http.end();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   
  }
  delay(10000);

}
```

Comment: Are you able to do the same request from your computer with a tool like Postman?

Comment: @GazihanAlankus
Yes I have tested the same API request with a tool like 'https://apitester.com/' and that works fine.